# Sending emails with PHPMailer()

Tags: php, timeout, phpmailer, newsletter

I have created a newsletter system and my question is: How should i write my code considering that i have to send that mail to hundreds of email addresses?

I've discussed with my host administrator and he told me that i should send my emails one by one but not more than 6 per minute.

Can i use the $Timeout property? If so, how?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sending the same mail to different recipients? Or a personalized mail to every person?

Comment: same email for many recipents

Comment: In this case you can outsource the heavy load to the smtp-server, just sending the e-mail once, with the recipients added as bcc (for privacy). So, not php is sending every mail, just one.
As Todd already mentioned, you can use Pear Mail, which is very powerful. Or, if you can't install it, PHPMailer() does a good job too.

Comment: that's right, i don't have permission to install pear packages an i tried to add the recipients as BCC but it doesn't work(it simply doesn't work, i get no error even if i write my code as try-catch)

Comment: @PvB: But mostly there are limits to the number of recipients you can send an email to, depending on providers's configurations.

Comment: @kmunky: Even with only a few recipients in BCC? And it does work with recipients in To? Maybe you could post your code?

Comment: yeah i tried even with 2 or 3 recipients and same thing.i followed the official phpmailer examples with bcc but..no success

Comment: finally it works with BCC now...crazy thing...i had to include the lang file too :D

Comment: @Marcel: You're right, there are restrictions. Not used to it anymore, own servers ;)

Answer (score 3):

If you have to send out the mails one by one (instead of using BCC), I'd use a database-queue to respect the limit of sending out only 6 mails per minute (no matter what solution you'll finally use to actually send the mails).

E.g. you'd have a database-table containing recipient, subject, mailbody, lastsenddate, timessent and status.

Save all mails, you will send out, to the database and then set up a cronjob that will run once a minute and check if there are still mails in the queue waiting to be send (e.g. status = "unsend"). Then you'd pick a maximum of 6 (or whatever your limit is) mails from the queue, send them out, set the status to "send" (and increase "timessent" and set "lastsenddate" to the actual time, if you like) and wait for the next cronjob until all mails are sent.

This way you have several advantages:

1. you can respect your per-minute-limit
2. you have all your mails in a database and can relate to them later (e.g. to find out how many mails - and which ones - you sent last Friday or to find out whether a certain address has been processed - and when and how many times - if someone claims he never received a mail / or too many)
3. by tracking a mail-status you could implement a bounce-handler that'll e.g. set a mail-status to "bounced" if a mail returns, so you could start a resend of your mailing some time later to reach addresses that returned a "mailbox full"-message the first time
4. by saving your mails to a database, you could even setup a "deferred mail service" by adding a database-field "starttime" and make your send-script respect this date, so you could already queue your Christmas-mails in spring :)

Comment: this is a great post, all i hope is to find some cronjob references :D i never worked with it. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Pear Mail will allow you to send email from PHP to allot of people.

http://pear.php.net/package/Mail/

Comment: But PEAR Mail has many problems and incompatibilities with PHP 5.3